# Magento 2 - Delete all products with ID 140.000 and higher

Tags: magento2, products, sql

We have a lot of duplicate products in our Magento 2 store, that we need to remove.

Now I am looking for a way or a sql query to remove all products from id 140.000 or higher.
So all products from 1 to 140.000 should remain.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not mess with the database directly. I'd rather write a PHP script that uses magento core objects to achieve this. Something like this should work:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap     = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
    
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
        $collection        = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    
        foreach ($collection as $product)
        { 
            $id = $product->getId();
            if($id >= 140000)
            {
                $registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
                $product->delete(); 
                $registry->unregister('isSecureArea'); 
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you need any further assistance !

Comment: If this solved your issue please mark it as answer, don't mean to nag you but I would appreciate that :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! We will try this, but is there a way to also include a reset for the product ID's? This so that it from now on will re-continu from 140000? Not that we are missing a lot of product id's in the future?

Comment: Get the following error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager' not found in /remove-products.php:3`

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Also make sure that you place the script file outside of the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and a few other tasks to complete in bulk. Check the following tool, we are using it for years now.

https://www.mag-manager.com/